# How to know when all Java2D rendering is finished, after a repaint() call?

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I have a standard paintComponent() method that draw some shapes on a Swing JPanel, via Java2D.

Initially, the JPanel surface is displayed with a clean white background.

After the user select a file, I build the shapes (in a separated thread) based on the instructions on the file.

Then, I call JPanel's rapaint() method, you know, will be handled at the EDT.

I can tell when the repaint() processing ends: I just need to look at the new drawings on the screen.

So, this morning I don't have many ideas to answer THE QUESTION: how to know the same information via code?

Comment: Can't you just add a notifier at the end of your paintComponent?

Comment: The notifier was just the boolean value returned by Graphics#drawImage()! Worked fine.

Comment: That's one option, but using it means that you have to periodically check the value of that variable in the other thread. I would have considered some more sophisticated solution, but if it works for you then I suppose it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any automatic notification, but you can set a boolean variable or call a method at the end of your paintComponent().

Note that normally you should not have this problem, because paintComponent() is supposed to contain only code that executes fast, any initialization/calculation should be moved to another method.

Comment: Thank you! I think a 'boolean variable' or a 'method call' can be tested with Graphics#drawImage() or with ImageObserver#imageUpdate() to help notify me about the pixels loaded on screen. Let me see, right now...

Comment: Hey @Iblalazscs, solved with the boolean value returned by drawImage at the end of the paintComponent()

Comment: If you have a BufferedImage, then drawImage should always return true (and you can use null as the ImageObserver). Anyway, if the answer was correct, you should accept it :)